How to show that this critical point is not in the critical sequence of a $j:V_\lambda\to V_\lambda$?
$\newcommand{\cr}{\mathrm{cr}}$This post uses the notion from model theory of elementary embedding, and uses notation such as $\mathcal E_\lambda$ (set of all nontrivial elementary embeddings $V_\lambda\to V_\lambda$) and $jk$ (application operation on $\mathcal E_\lambda$) that can be found in Laver's paper.
This is a basic fact in the study of $\mathcal E_\lambda$ which I can't reproduce. Let $j:V_\lambda\to V_\lambda$ be a nontrivial elementary embedding, and let $\kappa=\kappa_0=\cr(j)$, $\kappa_{n+1}=j(\kappa_n)$ be its critical sequence. According to Laver's "On the Algebra of Elementary Embeddings of a Rank into Itself", $\cr(((jj)j)(jj))$ is not in the critical sequence of $j$, but between $\kappa_2$ and $\kappa_3$. How is this shown?

Some work:
We will use the next lemma without mention: for any $k,\ell\in\mathcal E_\lambda$, any $\alpha<\lambda$, and any $x\in V_\alpha$, $k(\ell\cap V_\alpha)(x)=k(\ell)(x)$ due to $k(\ell\cap V_\alpha)\subseteq k(\ell)$.
The next lemma helps with computation of critical points of applications of embeddings.
Lemma: For $k,\ell\in\mathcal E_\lambda$, $\cr(k(\ell))=k(\cr\ell)$.
Proof: First we show $\cr(k(\ell))\leq k(\cr\ell)$. We have $V_\lambda\vDash f(\beta)\neq\beta$ where $\beta$ and $f$ are free variables interpreted as $\cr(\ell)+1$ and $\ell\cap V_{\cr\ell}$ respectively. Applying $k$, we get $V_\lambda\vDash k(\ell\cap V_{\cr\ell+1})(k(\cr\ell))\neq k(\cr\ell)$, and this holds in $V$ as well. Thus we have $k(\ell)(k(\cr\ell))\neq k(\cr\ell)$, i.e. $k(\ell)(\alpha)\neq \alpha$ for $\alpha=k(\cr\ell)$, so $\cr(k(\ell))\leq k(\cr\ell)$.
Now we show $\cr(k(\ell)\geq k(\cr\ell)$. We have $V_\lambda\vDash\forall(x\in V_\beta)(f(x)=x)$ where $\beta$ and $f$ are free variables interpreted as $\cr\ell$ and $\ell\cap V_{\cr\ell}$ respectively. Applying $k$, we get $V_\lambda\vDash\forall(x\in V_{k(\cr\ell)})(k(\ell\cap V_{\cr\ell})(x)=x)$, and this holds in V as well. Thus we have $\forall(x\in V_{k(\cr\ell)})(k(\ell)(x)=x)$, so $\cr(k(\ell)) \geq k(\cr\ell)$, so $\cr(k(\ell))=k(\cr\ell)$. $\square$
So $\cr(((jj)j)(jj))$ is $((jj)j)(\cr(jj)) = ((jj)j)(j(\cr(j))) = ((jj)j)(\kappa_1)$. I am not sure how to proceed from here. Applying properties of application and composition of embeddings (e.g. the properties listed in lemma 1.7 of Dehornoy's handbook chapter "Elementary embeddings and algebra") must not be enough, since the final result can't be $\cr(((jj)j)(jj)) = j(j(\ldots(j(j(\kappa)))\ldots))$ for any number of $j$'s. I may try directly showing that $((jj)j)(jj)(\kappa_2)=\kappa_2$ but there is a $\beta<\kappa_3$ such that $((jj)j)(jj)(\beta)\neq\beta$, but this seems like it would take a large amount of work.

I recall being shown this fact a couple of years ago by Andrew Brooke-Taylor via a drawing of the embeddings involved and the critical sequences.

@AsafKaragila Incidentally Andrew Brooke-Taylor seems to have an account on this site, although not a very active account. If nobody else answers this question in the next week or so, would it be a good idea to email him and self-answer with his response? (Given he grants permission for his response to be posted)

Andrew will probably take a few weeks, months, and on occasion, years to see your email. So, if you email him, don't feel bad if you don't hear back.

We have the critical sequence of $j$ is $\left<\kappa_n\right>_{n<\omega}$.
Note that the critical sequence of $j(j)$ is $\left<\kappa_{n+1}\right>_{n<\omega}$.
Now note that $j(j)(j)(\kappa_0)=\kappa_2$,
since $$j(\kappa_0)=\kappa_1,$$ and applying $j(j)$ to the just displayed equation yields
$$j(j)(j)\Big(j(j)(\kappa_0)\Big)=j(j)(\kappa_1),$$
and since $j(j)(\kappa_0)=\kappa_0$ and $j(j)(\kappa_1)=\kappa_2$, therefore
$$j(j)(j)(\kappa_0)=\kappa_2.$$
We also have $j(j)(j)(\kappa_2)=\kappa_3$, since
$$j(\kappa_1)=\kappa_2,$$
and applying $j(j)$ to this displayed equation yields
$$j(j)(j)\Big(j(j)(\kappa_1)\Big)=j(j)(\kappa_2),$$
and since $j(j)(\kappa_1)=\kappa_2$ and $j(j)(\kappa_2)=\kappa_3$, therefore
$$j(j)(j)(\kappa_2)=\kappa_3.$$
Now you asked about the critical point of $k=j(j)(j)\big(j(j)\big)$.
Well, $\mathrm{cr}(j(j))=\kappa_1$, so $\mathrm{cr}(k)=j(j)(j)(\kappa_1)$, but
$\kappa_0<\kappa_1<\kappa_2$, so
$$j(j)(j)(\kappa_0)<j(j)(j)(\kappa_1)<j(j)(j)(\kappa_2),$$
so combined with the equations derived above,
$$\kappa_2<j(j)(j)(\kappa_1)<\kappa_3;$$
that is,
$$\kappa_2<\mathrm{cr}(k)<\kappa_3.$$

Excellent! I may need some time to go through this answer, so it may be a while before I accept.
